# Pass form value to PHP variable using AJAX and redirect

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible for a user to enter a value into a form and then, on submit, have the page redirect to a new one with the value entered into the form stored in a PHP variable?

This if my form code;

```
<form id="loc-search" method="post">

    <input type="text" id="search-by-location" name="custom-location" value="" placeholder="Sheffield, UK"/>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value=""/>

</form>
```

Once the user has entered a value in `#search-by-location` the page needs to redirect to `weather.php` with the value stored in a PHP variable called `$location`

AJAX / JS aren't my strong suits so if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the argument `action="weather.php"` to your form tag. Then, when clicked on the submit button, you will get redirected to that page. Depending on your method, in your case `POST`, the input values will be available in the superglobal `$_POST` array in PHP.

In your example, `$location = $_POST["custom-location"];` will suffice. Note that the name, not the ID, determines the array key in the target PHP document.

Javascript or AJAX are not needed to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a normal form so why not just use `$_POST` after the redirect on the `weather.php` page:

```
$location = $_POST["custom-location"];
```

As **@Tacticus** pointed out you also need to have the form redirect (if you did not already do this in JS). By adding `action="weather.php"` in the form:

```
<form id="loc-search" method="post" action="weather.php" >
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Just that is not sufficient, as the user won't get redirected to the weather.php page. Adding the tag action as described in my answer will fix this.

Comment: @Tacticus You are correct, I'm assuming that the users form is directing to that page by some JS call. Since it's quite an elementary thing to do I assumed that the OP already handled that.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers you should modify your form to look like this:

```
<form id="loc-search" method="post" action="weather.php">

<input type="text" id="search-by-location" name="custom-location" value="" placeholder="Sheffield, UK"/>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value=""/>

</form>
```

In your weather.php file, you can get the value from the $_POST global variable, just like this:

```
<?php 
$location = $_POST["custom-location"];
//Interpret data

?>
```

Note that you can access the value of an input tag from your form witch was passed, with the input's **name**. In html you specify the following:

```
<input name="yourname" />
```

And when you want to access that value, you simply refer to his **name**.

```
$_POST['yourname']
```

If you use GET method for the form to pass the values, then you do the same, only the value will be stored in the $_GET global variable, so in your case with a GET method the variable initialization would look like this:

```
<?php 
$location = $_GET["custom-location"];
//Interpret data

?>
```